# How to make one default emtpy list equal another in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to utilise an existing list to add/copy/equal its values to another, empty default list I have. The purpose of this is so that I have a default list I can make arguments against later.

```
Amazon_Books_Old = ['Mary','Bob','Chris','Robert']
Active_List = []
def preview_button_execute():
    if variable.get() == "Amazon Books" and varChoice.get() == False:
        Active_List == Amazon_Books_Old
        Preview_Window()
#This executes the function defined above
Preview_Button = Button(Preview_Export_Label,text='Preview',command=preview_button_execute)
Preview_Button.pack(fill=X)
#This operates on the Active_List which should be updated with the new list data
label0=Label(Pre_Win,text="")
label0.grid(column=2,row=1)
label0['text'] = Active_List[0]
```

Everything I want this code block to do works, save for getting the list `Active_List` to be equal to `Amazon_Books_Old`, or to contain its values through other list copying methods. `list.copy(old_list)` and other methods don't seem to work either. For context, the `.get()` calls are based on Tkinter widgets, and are not relevant to the problem I am having.

Additional Information: Other methods suggested such as Active_List = Amazon_Books_Old.copy() result in label0['text'] = Active_List[0]
IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: You're *comparing*, not *assigning*. `==` means "is equal to", which will result in a False value you don't assign to any identifier.

Comment: I've looked at methods for doing that, such as list1=list2.copy(), but these all return an out of range error when the button is pushed, indicating to me that it is not actually updating Active_List with the values of Amazon_Books_Old.

Comment: If you have a problem with your button command, you have to post code with a button. Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: `Active_List = Amazon_Books_Old.copy()` would work just fine for what you're descibing. How you're *using* that list may be the actual problem.

Comment: Updated code to include button (thank you Aran-Fey), and added explanation that the previously tried methods such as list1=list2.copy() have been tried, and listed the error they display.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out:

```
def preview_button_execute():
if variable.get() == "Amazon Books" and varChoice.get() == False:
    global Active_List
    Active_List = Amazon_Books_Old.copy()
    Preview_Window()
```

Truly, I am not the best programmer around.

The Active_List = Amazon_Books_Old.copy() I had tried before posting (and was correctly suggested by a commenter) was probably actually working, but not updating the Active_List outside the function like I was wanting.

I have always avoided Global statements because I was told not to mess with them. (?)

Thank you to those that participated in this learning experience.